# Understanding the data flow when fetching chart data using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I am trying to create a test automation results dashboard using a JS library called Chart.JS. I would like to display a bar graph over time showing the total number of tests passed & failed.

To do this, I have done the following things:

1. Created a dash_proj.html file in which I include Chart.js and in this file I will actually be drawing the graph onto the canvas.
2. Created a .php file in which I use a PDO connection to query a local database copy on my machine (testing locally for now through localhost).
3. In that same .php file, I display, in text, the results onto the browser to ensure I have grabbed the appropriate data.

Now, I am getting confused as to the proper flow of things from here. From what I have read, the next step should be to use JavaScript to call an AJAX function and tell it which PHP file name to look at (the one running the MySQL query), and that will return the data in real time (no screen refresh). Within the HTML file, I should wait for the JavaScript to return that info and the final step will be the actually drawing of the graph.

Where does jQuery come into play? And can I just put my AJAX calls inside my php file which makes the query to the database?

I was thinking of testing to make sure that AJAX call is working by first inserting dummy data into the database and checking to see if the results appear in real time on my PHP file through localhost. I was thinking that the next step would be to store all of the data from my $query->fetch() into two different arrays (one for tests passed and one for tests failed), then somehow access that array from my HTML file which calls Chart.JS and stick that data into the draw bar graph function?

Comment: jquery is a helper library. it's just javascript. there's nothing in JS you couldn't accomplish yourself with "pure" javascript.

Comment: How're you getting on with this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use jQuery. This JavaScript library contains a number of functions to simplify making AJAX calls and accessing the DOM, though [some would argue](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) that the convergence of browser APIs make it less necessary these days. Nevertheless, it remains popular.

Your first task is probably to fire off an AJAX operation upon page load. You can start off by adding this JavaScript directly to the page, though you'll probably want to add it as a minified asset once you have your logic working.

```
function ajax() {
    // @todo Add your ajax logic in here
}

// Load the AJAX data into the chart as soon as the DOM is ready
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    ajax();
});
```

It is common to do read operations using a `get` operation returning JSON, for which [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) would work fine. Add this logic in place of the `@todo` comment above.

After that, you'll probably want to do a periodic refresh of your data, say every 60 seconds. You can do this thus:

```
setInterval(60 * 1000, ajax);
```

Note the interval timer works on milliseconds, hence the need to multiply by 1000.

One downside of the above is that if you expect a large number of users, or wish to reduce the interval to a very small value, your web server will be processing a lot of redundant requests (since most calls will result in no screen change). Using AJAX here is therefore not very scalable.

A better approach is to configure the server to push updates to browsers using Web Sockets. However, this requires a separate kind of web server, and so I probably would not recommend it for you just yet.